# swift syntax, check for nil before unwrapping

Tags: swift, swift3

I find checking `nil` before unwrapping is lengthy, is there a shorter way? I'm new to Swift, thanks

```
     func loadSettings(defaults: UserDefaults) {
       if defaults.string(forKey: "driverId") != nil {
         driverId = defaults.string(forKey: "driverId")!

       }
     }
```

Comment: This is all clearly explained with lots of examples in the Optionals section of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
if let driverId = defaults.string(forKey: "driverId") {
    // use driverId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func loadSettings(defaults: UserDefaults) {
    if let driverId = defaults.string(forKey: "driverId"){
     // process driverId
    }
 }
```